# NHibernate - ICompositeUserType without 'physical .NET style properties'

Tags: c#, nhibernate

The XML comment of the `ICompositeUserType` interface tells me:

```
This interface allows a custom type to define "properties".
--> These need not necessarily correspond to physical .NET style properties.
```

I have such case where I map multiple columns into a list:

```
// Each column is mapped into this object
public class IdentifiedValue
{
    public string Name;
    public object Value;
}

public class CompanyContainer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<IdentifiedValue> Values { get; set; }
}

// The columns being mapped:
public class GeneratedColumns
{
    public static string[] ColumnsInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
                {
                    "CODE_TYPE",
                    "CODE_VALUE",
                    "CODE_DESC_NL",
                    "CODE_DESC_FR",
                    "CODE_DESC_EN"
                };
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation of the ICompositeUserType:
(irrelevant methods omitted)

```
public class IdentifiedValueMapper : ICompositeUserType
{
    public string[] PropertyNames
    {
        get
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            foreach (var columnInfo in GeneratedColumns.ColumnsInfo)
            {
                result.Add(columnInfo);
            }
            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader dr, string[] names, ISessionImplementor session, object owner)
    {
        if (dr == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var result = new List<IdentifiedValue>();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        {
            var value = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(dr, names[i], session, owner) as string;
            result.Add(new IdentifiedValue()
                {
                    Name = names[i],
                    Value = value
                });
        }
        return result;
    }

    public IType[] PropertyTypes
    {
        get
        {
            var result = new List<IType>();
            foreach (var columnInfo in GeneratedColumns.ColumnsInfo)
            {
                result.Add(NHibernateUtil.String);
            }
            return result.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedClass
    {
        get { return typeof(List<IdentifiedValue>); }
    }
}
```

The mapping itself

```
public class CompanyContainerMap : ClassMap<CompanyContainer>
{
    public CompanyContainerMap()
    {
        Table("S1073_CODE");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("CODE_ID");
        var cols = Map(x => x.Values)
            .CustomType<IdentifiedValueMapper>()
            .Columns.Clear();

        foreach (var col in GeneratedColumns.ColumnsInfo)
        {
            cols.Columns.Add(col);
        }
    }
}
```

The failing test code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var factory = BuildSessionFactory();

        using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
        {
            var query = session.QueryOver<CompanyContainer>();
            query.Where(Restrictions.Eq("CODE_VALUE", "1"));
            var result = query.List();
            var blah = result;
        }
    }
```

The exception when executing the query:
`could not resolve property: CODE_VALUE of: CompanyContainer`

So it looks like it is still trying to access CompanyContainer.CODE_VALUE which doesn't exist. I'm unsure why it would want to access the .NET property as I only want to generate `WHERE CODE_VALUE='1'`.

Executing without the Where clause works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the documentation is not that great, it is not easy to identify this kind of stuff.

I debugged through the nhibernate code and found that nhibernate simply expects a certain property path for your list of properties which get stored within Value.

The path is `<PropertyName>.<key>`, so you can use something like this:

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Eq("Values.CODE_VALUE", "1"));
```

By the way, you can also achieve the same result by using dynamic component part mapping.

In your mapping, use this

```
DynamicComponent(p => p.Values, m =>
{
    foreach (var col in GeneratedColumns.ColumnsInfo)
    {
        m.Map(col).CustomSqlType("nvarchar(50)");
    }
});
```

instead of your value mapping and use for example `IDictionary` as type of Values

```
public virtual IDictionary Values { get; set; }
```

This will generate the same table structure and simply retrieves all the values into the dictionary.

The query works exactly the same way.

I think this way the code is much easier to understand and you can get rid of the `ICompositeUserType` implementation.

To create this a little bit more type safe you could add object type and sql type lists for your column definitions

```
public static string[] ColumnSqlTypes
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            "nvarchar(50)",
            "int",
            "nvarchar(255)",
            "nvarchar(255)",
            "nvarchar(255)"
        };
    }
}

public static Type[] ColumnTypes
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Int32),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(string)
        };
    }
}
```

and change the mapping to

```
public class CompanyContainerMap : ClassMap<CompanyContainer>
{
    public CompanyContainerMap()
    {
        Table("S1073_CODE");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("CODE_ID");
        DynamicComponent(p => p.Values, m =>
        {
            for(var index = 0; index < GeneratedColumns.ColumnsInfo.Length; index++)
            {
                m.Map(GeneratedColumns.ColumnsInfo[index])
                    .CustomSqlType(GeneratedColumns.ColumnSqlTypes[index])
                    .CustomType(GeneratedColumns.ColumnTypes[index]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now you'll see that if you query for

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Eq("Values.CODE_VALUE", "1"));
```

It will throw an exception because it expects an integer for CODE_VALUE!

Changing it to

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Eq("Values.CODE_VALUE", 1));
```

works perfectly fine.